# increase in one variable nested within another column in R + setting 0 as starting value

Tags: r, nested, diff

I'm trying to use the diff function to calculate the increase in a variable ("damage") in this dataset (df). I want to fill the column "damage_new" with this new variable. The values that you see now are the values I would like to have.

```
df = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2), trial=c(1,3,4,1,2), damage=(1,NA,3,1,5))
```

df

```
  ID  TRIAL DAMAGE DAMAGE_NEW  
  1      1    1      0  
  1      3    NA    NA  
  1      4    3     NA  
  2      1    1     0  
  2      2    5     4
```

If I run
 `diff(df$damage)`  it will calculate the difference in the whole dataset.

two things that I haven't managed are:
-how to nest the difference within the values of another column? Specifically, I want to calculate the damage increase (for the whole dataset), but within a single individual (ID), of which I have repeated measurements.
-I also would like to have the damage_new column to be the same length as the rest of the dataset (to attach it), and for each individual, have the first value of damage_new set to 0, since obviously the first measurement has no reference.
-To further describe the dataset, I have NAs in the 'damage" column, which I suspect will lead to more NAs in the damage_new column, but I would like to keep them (and I wonder how the function deals with them?). I also don't have the same number of measurements per individual (they will have a different number of trials, with some missing in between).

thanks a lot for the always fast and efficient answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dplyr` package is great for this kind of things:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(damage_new=c(0,diff(damage)))
Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
Groups: id

  id trial damage damage_new
1  1     1      1          0
2  1     3     NA         NA
3  1     4      3         NA
4  2     1      1          0
5  2     2      5          4
```

You can read more about `dplyr` usage [here](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/)

**Update**

If you'd like to go with the base R, you could do:

```
df$damage_new <- ave(df$damage,df$id,FUN=function(v) c(0,diff(v)))
```

which will produce the same `df`.

Answer (score 3):

Library `data.table` is your friend there:

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(df)
> setkey(df, id, trial)
> df[,new_damage:=c(0,diff(damage)),by=id]
> df
   id trial damage new_damage
1:  1     1      1          0
2:  1     3     NA         NA
3:  1     4      3         NA
4:  2     1      1          0
5:  2     2      5          4
```

On the `diff` working with `NA`, anything you withdraw from `NA` gives `NA`:

```
> diff(c(1,3,4,NA,5,7))
[1]  2  1 NA NA  2
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you need to set key in this example?

Comment: Little trick: setkey sets key ....but also order first by id and then by trial ! I do not assume the data.frame is already sorted and it does not make sense to use diff on non sorted data.frame- like on two non consecutive trials ;)

Comment: thanks! I ran the code from@MaratTalipov in R base and it worked! I had sorted the dataframe already by ID and then by TRIAL, so that the damage_increase would be calculated in the correct sequence. Thanks @Colonel Beauvel for the explanation on how diff deals with NAs.

Comment: If the intent is just to order, you can use `setorder`.